# Bitcoin initial communication diagram

Tags: client, protocol, bitcoin-core, tcp

I'm trying to understand how exactly does the Bitcoin client communicate initially with another client, as I'm making my own client and learning new things about TCP protocol. As I understand, the Bitcoin client uses the standard port (8333) as a server port that is listening to other clients' communication, and the client opens up new ports as it is trying to communicate with other clients. As I'm not sure if I understand the communication correctly, I made this chart:

[image]

My question is: is this diagram and my assumptions correct, or did I make some mistake in understanding how the protocol works?

Comment: Since this is TCP, it's probably clearer to simply state that A opens a TCP connection to B's port 8333 and that this connection is used for subsequent communication between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're pretty close, with the deviations being I think primarily in terminology.

Client A *listens* for connections on port 8333. *Listening* is a *server* activity.

Client A chooses an [ephemeral port](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port) and opens a connection to the address of Client B on port 8333, on which Client B is *listening*. At the TCP level, there is a [three-way handshake](http://www.inetdaemon.com/tutorials/internet/tcp/3-way_handshake.shtml) to establish the connection. Imagine this connection as a bi-directional pipe to and from which both clients can read and write.

Once established, Client A sends `Version` and Client B receives it. Client B sends `Version` and Client A receives it. Client A sends `Verack` and I think Client B also sends `Verack`, which is an acknowledgement of the version compatibility or receipt.

This is my understanding.